# Setup jar files

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I am trying to setup a smartGWT app and i have issue with the classpath jars.

First what does the term classpath mean.

What i did to setup the classpath is as follows:

create new classpath in eclipse from
1. Windows: Window  -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables
2. Selected New and entered a name SGWTPOWER_HOME and for path i selected the lib folder in $SGWTPOWER_HOME/lib

Then in my project i right click on the project title and select Properties -> Build Path.
Then i click on Variables and select the SGWTPOWER_HOME.

but my project gives me error "classes cannot be resolved". what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it to work. The steps that I did was all correct. Only that I was missing on that Extend button which I needed to clcik to add the jars. If the variable resolves to a folder, you can specify a path extension that points to a JAR. To do this press the Extend... button. Hope it will help new comers!!